# Google-Maps-for-Rails : Link for marker InfoWindow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails

I'm rebuilding a site using Ruby on Rails and thinking of using the excellent [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) gem.

The gem has the option to generate a list of customised links for all the markers as:

```
<ul id="markers_list">
 <li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Marker A</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Marker B</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

However, I need to add additional content, so rather than just showing a list of links I need to generate the following for each marker

```
<ul id="marker_a">
  <li><h3>Marker A</h3></li>
  <li>Details about Marker A</li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Show Marker A on Map</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone suggest the best way of going about this?

Comment: I'll take a look at it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked the project to enable a standalone link for each marker. Have a look at https://github.com/noddy/Google-Maps-for-Rails

In your model (using Location in this example) you need to add extra methods:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 def gmaps4rails_link
   id.to_s
 end

 def gmaps4rails_link_text
   "Show #{name} on Map"
 end
end
```

Then in your view (using HAML here), you could add the following:

```
- @locations.each do |location|
  %ul
    %li
      %h2
        = location.name
    %li{:id => "map_link_" + location.id.to_s}
```

and then call gmaps4rails properly using

```
 <%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"link_container" => "map_link_" } }) %>
```

Comment: +1 for your initiative but I won't add this feature to the gem: I'm upgrading it so that `to_gmaps4rails` will accept a block to include whatever needed by any developer in the json. My opinion is that this kind of things must be done by javascript otherwise you couldn't render the list when getting markers with ajax.